# How can I compile c++ app for ipod/iphone under linux(debian)

Tags: c++, iphone, ipod

How can I do this?
I search this info, about week, and all I find is this www.emdebian.org
I try to install g++ for arm platform on my PC, compile my app, copy it to my ipod, and it write "cannot execute binary file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, Apple uses a slightly different ARM binary format than the stock G++ does. I think you'll want to use LLVM-GCC or Clang.

Comment: Could you post a link? It will be cool if link will be to deb packages